# xCode FileMerge - "Line ending differ"

Tags: xcode, filemerge

When I open the 2 files as left & right in FileMerge,
I can see the things like the following screenshot.

[image: Image Uploaded]

As you can see, it doesn't show contents of the right file.

Before I saw this error, I did these things : Picked some difference things and chose "Choose left" and then Merged the two files.

After I did the things, I could see the error.

I want to know why and resolution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the bottom of your screenshot, it says "Line endings differ - left: Unix (LF), right: none"

My guess is you have to correct the line endings on your "2" file.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer, Shaggy Frog!